# google-app-engine : how to implement user logon success event

Tags: events, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm using google-app-engine in python language, I'm want to do something when user logon success event.

for example

```
def onlogin_success():
  user = users.get_current_user()
  log('user login %s' + user.nickname())
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate the login URL via [`create_login_url`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#create_login_url) and pass in a `dest_url` param.

The user will be taken to `dest_url` on successful login.